# is it possible to get input from the powershell script which is called as process?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

We have one PowerShell script file(.ps1) which ask user to provide input from PowerShell console and pass as an argument to another PowerShell script file(.ps1), this script file also ask for input from the user. for getting input we are using "***Read-Host***"

Below is the code snippet, while executing below code it is not asking input from the test2 script and process is stuck/pause.

can some help me how to achieve this use case ?

Code
**Test1.ps1**

```
[System.String] $ScriptPath = Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path

     $new_ip = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter IP"
    if([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($new_ip))
    {
     $pinfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
     $pinfo.FileName = "PowerShell.exe"
     $pinfo.RedirectStandardError = $true
     $pinfo.RedirectStandardOutput = $true
     $pinfo.UseShellExecute = $false
     $pinfo.WindowStyle = 'Hidden'
     $pinfo.CreateNoWindow = $True
     $pinfo.Arguments = "-file `"$ScriptPath\Test2.ps1`" -ServerIP `"$new_ip`""
     $p = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
     $p.StartInfo = $pinfo
     $p.Start() | Out-Null
     $stderr = $p.StandardError.ReadToEnd()
     $stdout = $p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
     $p.WaitForExit()
    
        
        if (![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($stderr))
         {
            Write-Warning "stderr: $stderr"
         }
         if($p.ExitCode -ne 0)
         {
            $isValidIP = $false
            Write-Warning " failed, Check above message"
          }
          else
          {
             Write-Host $stdout
             $isValidIP = $true
             Write-Host "Configured successfully"
          }
    }
    
    
    **Test2.ps1**
    
    Param([String]$ServerIP = $null
        )
    
    Write-Host "Server IP:"$ServerIP
    
    $SqlServerIP = (Read-Host -prompt "Enter Sql Server IP address (Default : localhost) ")
    Write-Host "Server IP:"$SqlServerIP
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you spawn a new process? Why not just invoke the second script directly from the first? eg. `$new_ip = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter IP"; .\script2.ps1 -ServerIP $new_ip`

Comment: Why `Read-Host`? Wouldn't it be better to use a mandatory parameter?

Comment: Do you have control over the second script? If you had a way to programmatically answer the second script's `Read-Host` prompt, what value would you use?

Comment: Hi Jessen we want user to execute second script from Powershell console as well and provide input so user can either execute Test1.ps1 and also can execute Test2 individually  from PowerShell Console

Comment: Hi mklement0 to answer your first question ->yes we want control over the second script. For second question we do not have any idea how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if we can redirect the user input prompt of a running process in background to the Main Window. But we can send the input to the process waiting for user input by using

```
$p.StandardInput.WriteLine("yourIP");
```

Not sure if this is the appropricate answer